# why there a .lock-wscript file after I run node-waf build

Tags: c++, node.js, waf

after I run `node-waf configure` and `node-waf build`, a `.lock-wscript` show in my folder, what's this? even I run `node-waf clean`, it still there. shall I keep it or remove it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Node uses ([used?](https://github.com/joyent/node/commit/3d3f29cf0626bcb1688da4fc0621b659a66fe4d9#wscript)) Waf as its build system, and the .lock-wscript file is used by Waf to know where the project's source and build directories are. The lock file is created when you run `waf configure` and is deleted when you run `waf distclean`. This latter command also deletes the build directory.

If you delete the .lock-wscript file then you will have to run `node-waf configure` before you can build the project again. Apart from that there's no real harm deleting it, but then it doesn't take up much disk space either :-)